# Стоимость перемещения участка памяти

Tags: память, x86, производительность

Какова будет стоимость перемещения\удаления участка в памяти, отображаемого на оперативную память, при учете того, что размер участка кратен одному из возможных размеров страницы в архитектуре x86 (допустим, 4KB)?

Comment: Ничего себе у вас задача, если такие вопросы становятся важными!

Comment: @VladD, это не задача, а мое любопытство :)

Comment: что есть удаление участка памяти ?

Comment: @eicto, стирание записи об участке из таблицы страниц.

Comment: что за таблица страниц ? вы про страничную организацию памяти ? как вы представляете "стирание"  ? обнуление ? сдвиг списка указателей ?

Comment: Зависит от аппаратуры и ОС. 

Обычно для аппаратуры MMU надо выставить комбинацию бит в PTE (Page Table Entry) процесса в какую-то из Not Valid, чтобы происходило прерывание по доступу.

Плюс к этому (точнее первым шагом) ОС (\*nix, про винду не знаю) уменьшает счетчик ссылок на данную физическую страницу, а при его обнулении переносит страницу в список свободных.